# Confused with the android release process - where is my keystore?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to find my keystore as I need to create a release API key for google maps and I need it for the certificate, except I dont know where my keystore is.

I am using a MacBook Pro with the latest OS.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're meant to generate it yourself, either within your IDE (If you're using Eclipse or Android Studio, the tools are already there).

But if you want to do it manually or your IDE doesn't have the ability to generate keystores, then you could follow the [official docs to generating a keystore](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for this, I am using Eclipse so I assume I can do it from in there then?

Comment: No problem. But in eclipse, I think the way to do it (Haven't used eclipse in a while), is to right click on your project and find 'android tools' from there click 'export signed apk' or something like that. It will then open up a wizard where you will eventually have the option to create a key store.

Now before you go on and do this, and this is probably the most important piece of advice I could give you: Back-up your keystore to just about anywhere, if you lose it, hehehe have fun trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio for Windows, just follow these steps:

1) Build > Generate Signed APK

2) "Create New...", choose a destination for the new .jks file, then enter all the data

3) Follow prompts, choose the destination for your new signed .apk, and you're finished

The steps for Mac are very similar, except for the paths.